# C++ read / write N exact bytes from file (even '00' bytes)

Tags: c++, file, byte, ifstream

My task is read file contents and place them into vector array of std::strings, then output from vector to another file.

I managed to solve it for file containing only normal text, but failed with, lets say .bmp
Here is .bmp file header:

```
BM)(     6   (   —  к        Р((
```

hex shows these are NULL bytes, not whitespaces

```
42 3d 06 29 28 00 00 00 00 00 36 00 00 00 ...
```

As a result , executing the following code

```
char *buffer = new char [50];

ifstream ifs( "file.bmp" , std::ifstream::binary );
ifs >> std::noskipws;

ifs.read( buffer, 50 );

std::string abc(buffer); //output it to other file next
```

i end up with buffer and abc strings equal to "BM)(6(—кР(( ..." with all nullbytes skipped.
ifs.read() was great until now. So whats the most comfortable way to read/write N exact bytes from a file ?

(I did a search but had difficulties with results)

Comment: @deleted If i, lets say, copy paste .bmp contents to a new text file (it will look the same, but all whitespaces become regular whitespaces) then it will work, but it wont be same data.

Comment: How do you know the buffer ends up with the content without the null bytes?

Comment: How are you printing your characters and how are you writing to your file? I just tried your code with the inclusion of a `std::ofstream` to test the writing of the data and it worked as I expected (50 bytes read, 50 bytes written)...

Comment: @0x499602D2 your comment led me to solution :)

Comment: @txtechhelp problem was improper copying from c string to std::string, as stated in my answer and is now solved

Answer (score 2):

That was lame, but somebody might google this someday so i ll write an answer.

If while debugging you would hover mouse over buffer after calling ifs.read() you would see "BM)(6(—кР(( ..." , but the null bytes are actually there. But (in MSVS) you couldnt see actual bytes buffer has unless you redefine buffer as

```
char buffer[50];
```

Next, when making std::string out of buffer, doing

```
string abc(buffer); // would not copy null bytes to std string,
```

So do this instead:

```
string abc(buffer, 50); //copies all bytes.
```

Now i have the real file contents in the string and if i output abc to other file i will have same data.

P.S. when checking results use hex editor to see real bytes, dont trust Notepad.